# Oracle Apex Web Development

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex-5

I am trying to build an Oracle Apex web page. I have the SQL query which I run in Db Visualizer and is fine. It's supposed to fetch about 7 million records but stops at 1000 because of limiting the rows in DB Vis.

This is my SQL query:

```
    select t.*, t.rowid from table t
    where  custedp =
           ( select min(custedp) from tablex
             where  fullorderno like substr('${ORD}$',1,8) || '%' );
```

I am trying to enter the ORD variable through a page item which is P2_new so my new SQL query is

```
    select t.*, t.rowid from table t
    where  custedp = 
           ( select min(custedp) from tablex
             where  fullorderno like substr(:P2_new,1,8) || '%' );
```

I created a region in the web page new (static content),page item (text field) p2_new and button submit which is going to submit the page. 
Everything until here is fine when I change the region new to a classic report from a static content the page doesn't load at all . It has a loading... on the tab and the address bar shows "about:blank" . I tried to validate the code and it also showed me an

```
     ajax call returned server error ora-20001 :error at line 1 error when I 
     tried to validate the code using the in built validator .
```

Comment: Maybe removing the semicolon?

Comment: Does the value `P2_new` have at least 8 chars?

Comment: No . It wasn't that .

Comment: the page is not loading for me to enter any value . The page in theory looks perfect but it's not loading at all . The SQL is fine .

Comment: It is probably because of the SQL . When I try it with a simple table it returns values quickly and also loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you plan to do with 7 million rows presented on a single page?

Anyway: classic report's query runs as soon as you navigate to that page. Thanks to `|| '%'`, query searches for `min(custedp)` throughout the whole `tablex`, without waiting for you to enter something into the `P2_NEW` item and press the `SUBMIT` button. So, if you wait long enough, it might return *something*.

Or, modify that query so that it runs if `P2_NEW` contains some value. For example:

```
select t.*, t.rowid 
from table t       
where custedp = (select min(custedp) 
                 from tablex 
                 where 1 = case when :P2_NEW is null then 2
                                else 1
                           end
                    and fullorderno like SUBSTR(:P2_new,1,8) || '%'
                );
```

Also, consider setting `P2_NEW`'s source *Always, replacing any existing value in session state*.

Comment: I don't want it to display 7 million rows . I wanted it to display one out of the 7 million . Your explanation makes sense . I don't understand how it can run the query when its not given with the value for the variable .

Comment: The first CASE condition will evaluate to `1 = 2` (i.e. *false*) when `P2_NEW` is null and query won't return anything. Once you put something into the item, it'll become `1 = 1` (i.e. *true*) and query might return the result (if `fullorderno like SUBSTR(:P2_new,1,8) || '%'` condition is met).

Comment: The "Always, replacing any existing value in session state" helped I think . I also changed the like to '=' .

Comment: Changing LIKE to = can't help, unless FULLORDERNO ends with a percentage sign. Besides, it is usual to "reward" someone who helped either by accepting their answer or upvoting it (instead of accepting your own (apparently, wrong) solution).

Comment: Calm down . I did up vote your answer . I just don't have a high enough reputation for my up votes to show . I accepted my answer because I thought that was the right solution with your supporting explanation  and I deleted it when it didn't work .

Comment: Oh, don't worry, I am calm. Wasn't 2-3 hours ago, while mowing the lawn at +30 degrees Celsius :)

Comment: This answer helped me a second time .

Comment: I'm glad if it did.

Comment: Littlefoot- https://stackoverflow.com/q/50917843/9894028 . Some help here ?