# Oracle Apex Radio Button

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a radio group with static values : A;1,B;2,C;3  . 1,2,3 are values from the column company where A,B,C belong .

This is my SQL query .

```
    Select  company into :p2_type from table where orderno = 
    :p2_orderno and rownum = 1;
```

This is a part of page 1 & 2 which are linked together .
I don't see a selected radio group when I move on to the next page although I see the orderno move over . I created a process in page 1 so that it runs this query when I click the 'next' button which also redirects me to the next page which is 2 .

Comment: First place I'd check is the Source attributes of `P2_TYPE`, in particular Type and Used. Second place I'd check is the other processes on the page, is anything else overwriting the item's value. Third place I'd look is the debug log to check that your query is actually being executed.

Comment: Also, check that the result of your query always returns one of the valid static values, or that you have enabled "show other values" for the radio button option.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont see a way to solve the problem . I have set it up so that it shows an error when I run the SQL and if it  doesn't work . It shows an error where the page item is at . The error statement it points to is the SQL statement I have .

Comment: I also tried to change it to a text field so that instead of selecting A,B, or C it just gives me the company value . I dont know if the problem is the SQL or something else .

Comment: There are two pages. Which page contains the radio group? Should be Page 2 (at least, that's what I understood). Query you posted runs on Page 1. Does Page 1 know value of P2_ORDERNO item (that belongs to Page 2, according to its name)? Finally, after reading everything you wrote, I'm not sure what's the question.

Comment: @Naq_23, one does not simply write a comment like *"It shows an error..."*. You must state what the error message actually says, for 70% of the time it will give you (or us) a clue as to what is going wrong.

Comment: OK @JeffreyKemp . I have set the page to show an error message if it doesn't work . That's what the message that shows up when I run the SQL and I dont know the reason why . Page 2 contains the radio group . I dont know how to check if page 1 knows the value of p2_orderno . Although p1_orderno and p2_orderno point to the same value . I am running the query on page 1  .

Comment: @Littlefoot my orderno in page 1 has a company division to it . I have 3 company division's chips;01,chocolates;15 and juices;20 . I have set these as static values in the radio group . When I do a select company from table where orderno = a123455 , it returns a value which is either 01,15 or 20 . I want Apex to be able to select chips,chocolates or juice and set it as the value based on the value returned within the radio group .

Comment: I think the first question to work on is if the value of p2_orderno is known at the time this is SQL run. From what you wrote I am guessing this SQL is run in a process when page 2 loads? If so then p2_orderno will only be known, in most all cases, if you are passing it to the page in the URL. 
Run your page in debug mode and you should be able to see the events in order to determine what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did . I changed the radio type to a select list . I still had the static values defined as  A;1,B;2,C;3 . Now when I select A or B or C and hit submit (I have linked the insert into column SQL to the submit button) it populates the table with a 1 or 2 or 3 . So my task has been accomplished but not in the way I wanted it to .